# Wrong font displayed at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I am using the Calibri font in some labels (winforms) and when I run my program, this label are displayed with a different font.
I had seen this problem when testing on computers without Office (hence no Calibri installed) but now I see it everywhere, even on my computer where Calibri is well installed (and I see the labels with Calibri in the designer ; then when I run in debug mode, I see another font).

The labels used to be displayed well, I've seen this problem only today (but could have been unnoticed for a few days, I'm not sure, but not long, that I'm sure).

There were a few windows updates yesterday, and some were for Office, but I'm not sure if it's relevant.
Bottomline is I have calibri, calibri is displayed in designer, and some other font is displayed at runtime..
And I seem to have the same problem with Segoe UI, but only when using the SemiBold style..

Here is an image of the result, on the left is runtime and on the right is the VS designer:

[image: Left is runtime, right is designer]

It is even more obvious when I try to use Calibri bold ; this time runtime is on the right and designer view on the left :

[image: Left for designer, right for runtime]

Comment: Sorry, winforms, I had put it in the title and it disappeared, I'll edit

Comment: you shouldnt put tags in the title.

Comment: it looks like its the right font, its just the rendering quality has changed.

Comment: OT: Is that button custom made or part of some GUI package?

Comment: Sorry about the tags, I had seen it around, I thought it was the way to do it, I'm still a newbie at posting here..
the button is custom made based on free PSDs, but the text is in an independant label.
As for if it's a different font or rendering I don't have the eye for it, but the designer one is already normal (not-bold) so the one at run time would be weird, cause it's the same size, and there's not style thiner than Normal in Calibri

Comment: ClearText seems not to be turned on.

Comment: How do you switch it ? I didn't change anything, it just happened, I really have no clue

Comment: @leppie Cleartext is definitely on in the second picture: http://imgur.com/CAE49

Comment: @Rotem: Yes, in Visual Studio... In the app (left), it is not.

Comment: @leppie In both. Notice the red/blue antialiasing on both sides. The app is the right one in the second picture, the designer is on the left.

Comment: @Rotem: Actually never noticed the second picture :) Yeah, it seems strange? Did the OP get the directions wrong?

Comment: Red/Blue AA ?? Nope the directions are right, they're inverted between the two pics only because it was easier this way to put side by side, sorry if it's a little confusing !

Comment: @Rotem : Ok, good catch ! I zoomed in and yes this is definitely the same font with and without that red and blue AA, any idea why that is ?

Comment: Although I'm not so sure about the same-font thing, notice the "t" ? in designer (good calibri) the "t" is attached to the next letter (or to the other "t" in "ette", and at runtime its far from that, AA cannot be responsible for that

Comment: Just going to throw this in, just in case it makes any difference...Are you setting this...Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault before running your application?

Comment: @activwerx : No !! Someone edited the Program.cs to add Mutex and must have deleted it in the process ! I added it back and it's all good again, thank you ! :)

Comment: @MickaelV. Cool, I'll add that as an answer then. Glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you create a new Windows Forms application in Visual Studio, the template includes the following lines

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(/*new instance of your form*/);
```

This line in particular will likely affect how text is rendered in your application.

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```