# Monotype Crosiva font style doesn't appear in winform as it's appearance in MS word

Tags: c#, winforms

in my winform i have a label and i changed it's font type to specific one called (Monotype Corsiva).
but the font style doesn't appear as it's appearance in MS word (see next image)

[image: 1 and 2]

1 is the font style as it appear in Microsoft word ,  2 is the my label in My Winform "*Clipped from the form*"

the font doesn't support regular, i make it **italic** and it doesn't worked, i also tried to **re-instill** the font and no changing. can any one help my?

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13741702/3585500

Comment: @ourmandave Thank you very much. it's worked

Answer (score 0):

I recently embedded a font in my WinForms exe to ensure it exists on a users computer because I was having simmilar issues.

1. Add the Font file to your Resources.resx
2. Add code to load the Font by reading the generated property

   ```
   byte[] fontData = Properties.Resources.FONT_RESOURCE_NAME_HERE;

   IntPtr fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
   uint dummy = 0;
   fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fontData.Length);
   AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)fontData.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);

   Font memoryLoadedFont = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 16.0F);
   ```
3. Change the `.Font` property of your target `Control`

   ```
   this.Font = memoryLoadedFont
   ```

Ofcourse you could just read the bytes from any other place :)